# Webots Qt framework libraries

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, webots

I am creating a **Webots** project on OSX, where I am including the following:

```
 #include <core/MainApplication.hpp>
```

I get error

> In file included from
>   /Applications/Webots/resources/projects/default/libraries/qt_utils/core/MainApplication.hpp:17:
>   /Applications/Webots/webots.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/QApplication:1:10:
>   **fatal error: 'qapplication.h' file not found**
>
> include "qapplication.h"
>
> 1 error generated.

All contnet of  /Applications/Webots/webots.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/QApplication:

```
#include "qapplication.h"
```

1. **QApplication** file content is too short. Also it seems like I cannot find **qapplication.h** on the file system, is that normal?
2. Would it be more sensible to use local installation of Qt framework than the one that comes with Webots? How do I change the .pro file then to link to local installation of Qt rather than to `/Applications/Webots/resources/projects/default/libraries/qt_utils`

My make file:

```
CXX_SOURCES = entry_points.cpp

QT = core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
USE_C_API = true

QT_UTILS = /Applications/Webots/resources/projects/default/libraries/qt_utils
INCLUDE = -I"$(QT_UTILS)"
LIBRARIES = -L"$(QT_UTILS)" -lqt_utils

space :=
space +=
WEBOTS_HOME_PATH=$(subst $(space),\ ,$(strip $(subst \,/,$(WEBOTS_HOME))))
include /Applications/Webots/resources/Makefile.include
```

**EDIT:**
I have discovered that when I try to run **make** in the folder: */Applications/Webots/resources/projects/default/libraries/qt_utils*
I get many errors (**among many others**), such as:

> /Applications/Webots/webots.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/QWidget:1:10:
>   **fatal error: 'qwidget.h' file not found**
>
> include "qwidget.h"
>
> ...
>   /Applications/Webots/webots.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/QObject:1:10:
>   **fatal error: 'qobject.h' file not found**
>
> include "qobject.h"
>
> ...
>   /Applications/Webots/webots.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/QApplication:1:10:
>   **fatal error: 'qapplication.h' file not found**
>
> include "qapplication.h"

In facts, these files are indeed missing from the Webots qt_utils

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of this line:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Indeed, `QT_MAJOR_VERSION` and `greaterThan` are not a part of the Webots Makefile system. If the Qt `widgets` module is not present, then the `qapplication.h` cannot be found (because it is precisely defined in the `widgets` module). As Webots is using Qt 5 since a while, I would recommend you to simply define the Qt modules like this:

```
QT = core gui widgets
```

Comment: 'qapplication.h` is not found even if I use 'QT = core gui widgets

Comment: Is WEBOTS_HOME defined correctly? https://www.cyberbotics.com/guide/compiling-controllers-in-a-terminal.php

Comment: Could you run the following command to determine if qapplication.h is in your system? `$ find /Applications/Webots/ -name qapplication.h`

Comment: $ find /Applications/Webots/ -name qapplication.h  
/Applications/Webots//resources/projects/robots/nao/aldebaran/simulator-sdk/include/Qt/qapplication.h  
/Applications/Webots//resources/projects/robots/nao/aldebaran/simulator-sdk/include/QtGui/qapplication.h

Comment: Which Webots version are you using? I have this file here: /Applications/Webots/webots.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qapplication.h

Comment: The version is 7.4.3

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to upgrade to Webots 8.4.